# Wrap element with anchor based on parameters of current url

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use .wrap() to turn an element into an anchor like so:

```
$( "img.ct-logo" ).wrap( "<a href='http://www.mywebsite.com'></a>" );
```

However, the href should be different depending on the current url.

For example if the url is https://www.mywebsite.com/es/

Then the anchor should include `/es/` like so:

```
$( "img.ct-logo" ).wrap( "<a href='http://www.mywebsite.com/es/'></a>" );
```

What kind of function do I need to first check the current url and wrap the element appropriately based on the current url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably just need to check if "/es/" is included in the URL, so I would do something like this:

```js
let theUrl = "www.website.com";

if(window.location.href.indexOf("/es/") > -1){
  theUrl = "www.website.com/es/";
}

$( "img.ct-logo" ).wrap( "<a href='" + theUrl + "'></a>" );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use: `window.location.href` instead of hardcoding the url.